# How to add 'about us' option in Android menu?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When the user will click on 'about us'(i've added' about us' on res>menu>main.xml)a new window or activity will come.How to do this?

Comment: Which 'about us' button are you talking about ? In the app manager ? Could you post a screenshot of your phone with this button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create `xml` file in

> res -> menu -> main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about_us"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="About Us"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

In **Activity**,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_about_us)
    {
        // Start AboutUs activity here
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much :-) it works greatly

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a new XML-LayOut File.
The easiest and fastest way is to set in the 
onOptionsItemSelected:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.actionaboutus)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped :-)